# SQLAlchemy is deletion on before_commit safe?

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I am using SQLAlchemy and try to manage a model "Media" which has a many-to-one relationship with a "Booking". Is it safe to call `scoped_session.delete()` from within a `before_commit` event?

```
def before_commit(session):
    r""" Invokes the ``before_commit`` method on all items in the session.
    This allows the models to perform an update-action depending on their
    new data. """

    for item in session.deleted:
        if hasattr(item, 'before_commit'):
            item.before_commit(session, 'deleted')

    for item in session.dirty:
        if hasattr(item, 'before_commit'):
            item.before_commit(session, 'dirty')

    for item in session.new:
        if hasattr(item, 'before_commit'):
            item.before_commit(session, 'new')

event.listen(db.session.__class__, 'before_commit', before_commit)

class Booking(db.Model):

    # ...

    media = db.relationship(Media, backref='booking')

    def before_commit(self, session, status):
        r""" Validates the booking's data. If the booking is being deleted,
        all its media will be deleted with it. """

        if status == 'deleted':
            # Delete all the media that is associated with this booking.
            for media in self.media:
                session.delete(media)
```

Answer (score 1):

a mass delete() using either session.execute("delete...") or session.query(cls).delete() should be fine, it just emits that SQL on the current connection.

As far as session.delete(obj), it looks like before_commit() is invoked before the final flush(), so in that sense you can treat it like a before_flush() event.  Try it out and you should see the DELETE being emitted, and if so then you're fine.